# Codename One building project locally doesn't recognize facebook JAR on classpath

Tags: codenameone

I am trying to get Codename One work on my Ubuntu machine locally so that I don't have to send builds to codenameone.com. I followed the steps in this tutorial:

http://sjhannah.com/blog/?p=228

and installed all successfully. when I go to my project directory and run:

```
ant build-for-android-device-locally
```

I get the following error:

```
/home/petr/projects/MyApp/dist/android/src/com/codename1/social/FacebookImpl.java:37: error: package com.facebook does not exist
```

So I downloaded the facebook sdk, compiled it using Gradle, and added the generated facebook JAR file to the CLASSPATH variable in my /etc/bash.bashrc file:

```
CLASSPATH="/home/petr/android-sdk-linux/platforms/android-21/android.jar:/home/petr/projects/MyApp/lib/CLDC11.jar:/home/petr/projects/MyApp/lib/CodenameOne_SRC.zip:/home/petr/projects/MyApp/lib/CodenameOne.jar:/home/petr/android-sdk-linux/extras/google/google_play_services/libproject/google-play-services_lib/libs/google-play-services.jar:/home/petr/android-sdk-linux/facebook-android-sdk-3.23.0/facebook/build/libs/facebook-3.23.0-sources.jar"
export CLASSPATH
```

Then I closed my terminal, reopened it again and tried to build using  ant again, but I keep getting the same "com.facebook does not exist" error. Why doesn't java recognize the JAR file?

Answer (score 0):

Check the version of the facebook sdk you used. In version 4, the package names changed from com.facebook to com.facebook.android. I recommend you use version 3.23.1